# Subset with condition in data table

Tags: r, if-statement, datatable, data.table

Assume we have data like this:

```
tmp <- data.table(id1 = c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3), time=c(1,2,3,4,1,2,3,1,2), user_id=c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,1,1) )
```

for each `user_id`, I want the all samples except the ones with `time > 2`  when `id1 == max(id1)`.

I use following code now and it give me the warning message like this:

```
tmp1 <- tmp[, if (id1 == max(id1)) .SD[time <= 2,] else .SD  , by="user_id"] 

Warning messages:
1: In if (id1 == max(id1)) .SD[time <= 2, ] else .SD :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
2: In if (id1 == max(id1)) .SD[time <= 2, ] else .SD :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

I guess it is due to the vectorize problem of if else statement. So I change my code to following:

```
tmp2 <- tmp[, ifelse(id1 == max(id1), .SD[time <= 2,] , .SD)  , by="user_id"]

Error in `[.data.table`(tmp, , ifelse(id1 == max(id1), .SD[time <= 2,  : 
  Supplied 4 items for column 5 of group 1 which has 6 rows. The RHS length must either be 1 (single values are ok) or match the LHS length exactly. If you wish to 'recycle' the RHS please use rep() explicitly to make this intent clear to readers of your code.
```

How can I correct my code?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do :

```
library(data.table)
tmp[, .SD[!(id1 == max(id1) & time > 2)], user_id]

#   user_id id1 time
#1:       1   1    1
#2:       1   1    2
#3:       1   1    3
#4:       1   1    4
#5:       1   3    1
#6:       1   3    2
#7:       2   2    1
#8:       2   2    2
```

Comment: Sorry for confusing, since I want "for each user_id", the desired output should have 8 rows

Comment: Thanks for the help, it stucks me around 2hrs, and your clean answer just reminds me the importance of logics.

Answer (score 1):

Using dplyr:

```
tmp %>% filter(!(id1 == max(id1)) & time > 2)
```

Or with base R:

```
tmp[tmp$id1 != max(id1) & tmp$time > 2, ]
```